# Device that improves with time

Tags: reliability

I am unable to find an example of a device that improves with time, i.e., every time you use the device, the probability of it failing is less than before.

I understand that it is an example of negative ageing but where does it actually happen in practical life?

Comment: Learning systems (synthetic and biological) improve as they're exposed to more data. Many mechanical devices have break-in periods where function initially improves with wear (e.g. machinery, leather boots), but breakdown will eventually occur. And, let's not forget about whisky stored in oak casks.

Comment: This is how in principle Google and any other service offering recommendations or personalized content should work. But I'm not sure how your question is related to statistics or ML?

Comment: This comment does not specifically address your query wrt machine learning. However an underlying assumption of virtually *any* scaled process -- learning, economic, financial, biological -- which monotonically increases with experience and time has been expressed by Nobel Laureate W. Brian Arthur as *increasing returns to scale*, sometimes described as a variant of the many laws of proportionate growth.

Comment: It would be exactly what you hope for in a good data analyst.

Comment: Human children before the age of about 8-9 years?

Comment: The examples above are interesting but I was more interested in a device with this property. If anybody has idea about it, please share.

Comment: Given that comment how is the device you're envisioning any different from a *perpetual motion machine*? Here's a quote from a wiki article about that, "Perpetual motion is motion of bodies that continues indefinitely. A perpetual motion machine is a hypothetical machine that can do work indefinitely without an energy source. This kind of machine is impossible, as it would violate the first or second law of thermodynamics." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion  In other words there may be a very good reason why you are "unable to find an example of a device that improves with time."

Comment: Tiny factual correction: at the time of writing W. Brian Arthur is not a Nobel Laureate. How far monotonic increase implies increasing returns to scale is something best debated otherwise.

Comment: That correction is correct. Arthur has won many other prizes for his work in economics but no Nobel.